# ExecutorService fixed pool hangs on a single task

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

My code has a thread pool implemented with `ExecutorService` fixed thread pool.
Most of the tasks executed by the pool are very short but at times there is one task that will run for a long time, about 20-30 seconds.
When this task runs, new tasks are not executed and will only resume when the long running task completes.

The pool is set to 20 so that's not the problem as I can recreate this with only 2 threads running, first is the long running one and the second gets stuck.

I've been wracking my head on why it is stuck and then I switched from `newFixedThreadPool()` to `newCachedThreadPool()` and the bottleneck was released. This is the only change I've done.

Does this behavior make sense?
Code seems to run fine so I guess I'll keep the change and as far as I understand, it is better to use cache thread pool if you are running many short tasks, but I was wondering why the fixed pool gets hang and is there a way to fix it?

Also, what could possible be a side affect, if any, for switching from fixed to cache?

Thanks.

Comment: Does not seem to make sense. Are you sure you did not change anything else?

Comment: When the problem appears again, do a `kill -QUIT` to get all threads' stack traces to see what they are doing.

Comment: It all depends on how you built your thread pool. Show us the code, and we could find the reason.

Comment: Is the long running task holding any locks while processing? Using eg visualvm or yourkit you should be able to see what locks are held (even better if you can slow your long task down to 60+ sec)

Comment: I second that we should be able to better help with the code posted.

Comment: Do a thread-dump and see why/what it's holding. Also please post the code. (1) ps -el | grep java (2) jstack <pid>

Answer (score 0):

Possible result is more threads will be running at the same time, because *newCachedThreadPool()* allow to run Integer.MAX_VALUE threads count.

It's hard to guess side affect without viewing of your code.

But as i think, if there is a problem witch solved by increasing threads count there is big chance that you has locks.

For example you has 4 resources A, B, C, D.
And 4 tasks:

1) short TaskA require resource A
2) short TaskB require resource B
3) short TaskC require resource C
4) long TaskD require resource A and D

So in one moment of time we will have next situation:

```
Thread1: TaskA await for resource A
Thread2: TaskD has A and D and running

TaskB wait in Queue
TaskC wait in Queue
```

When you change pull to pull with unlimited thread count, or fixed thread pool with many allowed threads:

```
Thread1: TaskA await for resource A
Thread2: TaskD has A and D and running
Thread3: TaskB has resource B
Thread4: TaskC has resource C
```

So, one of the threads is blocked by another one, but you can't see that because all another task are executed without locks.